# What does negative absolute temperature mean?

Tags: thermodynamics

I always understood that the concept of absolute temperature stems from the third law of thermodynamics and that the lowest theoretical possible temperature is zero degrees Kelvin.

However, recently I came across [an article published in *Science* (4th January 2013) titled "Negative Absolute Temperature for Motional Degrees of Freedom"](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/339/6115/52).
Given at the end of this question is the abstract of the said article.
This article was also covered [on Nature.com](http://www.nature.com/news/quantum-gas-goes-below-absolute-zero-1.12146) in a somewhat more pop-science style, however I'm still unable to understand what the article is trying to cover.

What does negative absolute temperature mean in the given context?

> **Article's abstract:**
>
> Absolute temperature is usually bound to be positive. Under special
>   conditions, however, negative temperatures—in which high-energy states
>   are more occupied than low-energy states—are also possible. Such
>   states have been demonstrated in localized systems with finite,
>   discrete spectra. Here, we prepared a negative temperature state for
>   motional degrees of freedom. By tailoring the Bose-Hubbard
>   Hamiltonian, we created an attractively interacting ensemble of
>   ultracold bosons at negative temperature that is stable against
>   collapse for arbitrary atom numbers. The quasimomentum distribution
>   develops sharp peaks at the upper band edge, revealing thermal
>   equilibrium and bosonic coherence over several lattice sites. Negative
>   temperatures imply negative pressures and open up new parameter
>   regimes for cold atoms, enabling fundamentally new many-body states.

Comment: @Danu Thanks, I didn't find that question via the search.

Comment: I'm making this a comment rather than an answer as this is a duplicate. The natural statistical mechanics definition of temperature is $\frac 1 T = \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}$. The number of microstates consistent with the given macrostate (aka Boltzmann entropy) grows as energy increases in most systems. It is possible to construct systems where Boltzmann entropy decreases after some point. In those specially constructed systems, 1/T becomes negative, and hence so does temperature. In a sense, these negative temperatures are extremely hot, hotter than any finite positive temperature.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature

Comment: [Lots of related questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=negative+temperature)